# How to update DOM in each loop iteration?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following class:

```
// Population class
class Population {

    constructor(size, target, mutationRate, minFitness) {
        this.target = target;
        this.size = size;
        this.individuals = [];
        // contains phrases (strings)
        this.matePool = [];
        this.mutationRate = mutationRate;
        this.bestFitness = 0;
        this.bestPhrase = "";
        this.totalGenerations = 0;
        // Stopping criterion
        this.minFitness = minFitness;
    }

    clearMatePool () {
        this.matePool = [];
    }

    addIndividual(newIndividual) {
        this.individuals.push(newIndividual);
    }

    evaluate() {
        let fitness = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
            fitness = this.individuals[i].fitnessFunct(this.target);
            // Update best fitness and best phrase
            if (fitness > this.bestFitness) {
                this.bestFitness = fitness;
                this.bestPhrase = this.individuals[i].getGenotype();
            }
        }
        // Stopping criterion
        if (this.bestFitness < this.minFitness) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    buildMatePool() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
            let n = Math.round(this.individuals[i].getFitness() * 100);
            for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                this.matePool.push(this.individuals[i].phrase);
            }
        }
    }

    reproduce() {
        // Create new generation
        for (let i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
            // Pick 2 parents
            let a, b, child, midpoint;
            while (true) {
                // Index of parentA
                a = getRandomIntInclusive(0, this.matePool.length - 1);
                // Index of parentB
                b = getRandomIntInclusive(0, this.matePool.length - 1);
                // Be sure you have picked two unique parents (phrases)
                if (this.matePool[a] === this.matePool[b]) {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Crossover
            child = this.crossover(a, b);
            // Mutation
            this.mutation(child);
            // The new child is part of the new population
            this.individuals[i] = child;
        }
        this.totalGenerations += 1;
    }

    crossover(a, b) {
        let child = new Individual(this.target.length);
        child.setGenotype("");
        let midpoint = getRandomIntInclusive(0, this.target.length-1);

        for (let i = 0; i < this.target.length; i++) {
            if (i < midpoint) {
                child.phrase = child.phrase + this.matePool[a].charAt(i);
            }
            else {
                child.phrase = child.phrase + this.matePool[b].charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return child;
    }

    mutation(individual) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.target.length; i++) {
            // The block inside the conditional statement would be executed 1% of the time.
            if(Math.random() < this.mutationRate) {
                // replace char with a new random character
                individual.phrase = individual.phrase.substr(0, i) + String.fromCharCode(getRandomIntInclusive(32, 128)) + individual.phrase.substr(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

I have the following DOM elements:

```
// Shows the current generation
var totalGenerationsHTML = $('#total-generations');
// Shows the best phrase so far
var bestPhraseHTML = $('#best-phrase');
// Shows the best fitness so far
var bestFitnessHTML = $('#best-fitness');
// Shows the result of the reproduction process (child)
var processingHTML = $('#processing');
```

And the following code section:

```
var condition = population.evaluate();

while (condition) {
    // Processing
    population.buildMatePool();
    population.reproduce();
    population.clearMatePool();
    condition = population.evaluate();
}
```

I need to update the value of the DOM elements in each iteration. I've tried different loop implementations using **setInterval()** and **setTimeout()** but the output was out of sync. Any help will be useful.

P.S. I am new to JavaScript. Please excuse any mistakes.

Comment: It would be nice to have context here because nothing makes any sense at all. Please provide all of the links you have copied this Frankenstein code from. Please explain what do you think it should do as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (condition) {}
```

Is so called blocking code, since that loop runs without giving the browser a chance to actually render the result, you wont see anything and probably the UI freezes.

You need to use either `setTimeout`, `setInterval` or as recommended for animation `requestAnimationFrame`

> but the output was out of sync

Changing the DOM and so visible things on a page is an asynchronous Process and while Js is running, the browser does not repaint. A `while` loop is running JS.

For more detailed information have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128683/how-to-make-a-function-which-counts-for-3-seconds/40128718#40128718)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `requestAnimationFrame()`. I did my research and it turns out to be the best way to update the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

@philipp was right. `requestAnimationFrame()` is the solution.

Basically `requestAnimationFrame()` is:

1. Synchronized with browser repaint (`setTimeout` and `setInterval` are not)
2. Optimized for animation
3. Runs as fast as the screen will allow
4. Battery saver

The following HTML/JS/CSS snippet demonstrates the use of `requestAnimationFrame()`.

```js
var currentPos = -200;

var element = document.getElementById("heading");

// Animation loop
function moveRight() {
  currentPos += 5;
 heading.style.left = currentPos + "px";
 window.requestAnimationFrame(moveRight);
 if(currentPos >= 800) {
   currentPos = -200;
 }
}

moveRight();
```

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

div {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lime;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Animation Loops</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <p>requestAnimationFrame()</p>
   <ol>
    <li>Synchronized with browser repaint</li>
    <li>Optimized for animation</li>
    <li>Runs as fast as the screen will allow</li>
    <li>Battery saver</li>
   </ol>
   <p>
    Traditionally to create an animation in JavaScript, we relied 
    on setTimeout() called recursively or setInterval() to 
    repeatedly execute some code to make changes to an element 
    frame by frame, such as once every 50 milliseconds. What we 
    specify as the delay (ie: 50 milliseconds) inside these 
    functions are often times not honoured due to changes in user 
    system resources at the time, leading to inconsistent delay 
    intervals between animation frames.
   </p> 
   <p>
    <strong>DO NOT</strong> use setInterval() or setTimeOut() for 
    animations, use requestAnimationFrame() instead.
   </p>
   <h1 id="heading">Animation Loops</h1>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```